# Send Email - Keep Cell Formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, getstring

I have a google spreadsheet that sends student information contained in a column that is queried and concatenated from another sheet. The queried information is separated by carriage returns.  This column is then emailed to families triggered by a formula that calculates how many carriage returns should be in the cell.

That part I have taken care of in the sheet itself.  I need assistance with emailing the column and maintaining the format of the cell. I've been able to do that with the code I have below, but it sends ALL of the data in column D in every email.  I need it to only send what's located in the appropriate row for the email.

The main portion of the code that's giving me trouble, I think, is the following:

```
var OriginalString = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("D2:D").getValues();
var NewString = OriginalString.toString().replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
```

Any help would be appreciated!

```js
function SendEmail3() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet3');
    var startrow = 2;
    var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
    var lastCol = 10;
    var range = ss.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, lastCol);
    var data = range.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var row = data[i];
        var AccountName = row[0];
        var email = row[1];
        var Parent = row[2];
        var Consent = row[4];
        var StudentData = row[3];
        var CarriageReturns = row[6];
        var Trigger = row[7];
        var emailSent = row[8];
        var subject = "Your Application";
      var OriginalString = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("D2:D").getValues();
        var NewString = OriginalString.toString().replace(/\n/g, '<br>');

        var message = "<HTML><BODY><font size=4>" +
            "<P>" + "Hello " + Parent + ','
            +"<BR>
            +"<BR>" + NewString + "<BR>"
                        +"</HTML></BODY>";
        var recipientsTo = email;
        if (AccountName.length > 0 && Trigger >= CarriageReturns && emailSent != 'EMAIL_SENT') {
            MailApp.sendEmail({
                subject: subject,
                to: recipientsTo,
                htmlBody: message
            });
            ss.getRange(startrow + i, 9).setValue('EMAIL_SENT');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what your looking for?

I set it up so that you can see the message on a modeless dialog rather than sending emails.

```
function SendEmail3() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  var startrow = 2;
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = 10;
  var range = ss.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, lastCol);
  var data = range.getValues();
  var html='';//Remove
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var AccountName = row[0];
    var email = row[1];
    var Parent = row[2];
    var Consent = row[4];
    var StudentData = row[3];
    var CarriageReturns = row[6];
    var Trigger = row[7];
    var emailSent = row[8];
    var subject = "Your Application";
    var NewString = StudentData.split('\n').join('<br />');
    //var message = "<HTML><BODY><font size=4>" + "<P>" + "Hello " + Parent + ',' + "<BR>" +"<BR>" + NewString + "<BR>" +"</HTML></BODY>";
    var message=Utilities.formatString('<HTML><BODY><font size=4><P>Hello %s,<BR><BR>%s<BR></HTML></BODY>', Parent,NewString);
    var recipientsTo = email;
    if (AccountName.length > 0 && Trigger >= CarriageReturns && emailSent != 'EMAIL_SENT') {
      //MailApp.sendEmail({subject: subject,to: recipientsTo,htmlBody: message});
      html+=Utilities.formatString('%s- %s',i+1,message);//Remove
      //ss.getRange(startrow + i, 9).setValue('EMAIL_SENT');
    }
  }
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);//Remove
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Email Message');//Remove
}
```

- [Utilities.formatString()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatString(String,Object...))

Comment: That returns all of the data in column D in the email and removes the formatting, unfortunately.

Comment: Now I can see what you were trying to accomplish.  Thanks for the data.